# Como colocar um um texto na tela do pygame?

Tags: pygame

Estava tentando colocar um texto dentro de uma tela do pygame em uma coordenada específica, o que posso fazer para imprimir um texto e restringir sua área?

```py
    import sys, pygame
    pygame.init()

    size = width, height = 800, 600
    speed = [0, 0]
    black = 0, 0, 0

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    fundo = pygame.image.load("baner.jpg")
    dialogo = pygame.image.load("dialogo.png")
    estatico = fundo.get_rect()

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        estatico = estatico.move(speed)
        if estatico.left < 0 or estatico.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
        if estatico.top < 0 or estatico.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]

        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(fundo, estatico)
        screen.blit(dialogo, estatico)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Isso é o que tenho até agora, duas imagens e queria colocar um texto em cima da caixa de diálogo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

```
from pygame import font

txt='hello world'                                 ##### armazena o texto
pygame.font.init()                                ##### inicia font
fonte=pygame.font.get_default_font()              ##### carrega com a fonte padrão
fontesys=pygame.font.SysFont(fonte, 60)           ##### usa a fonte padrão
txttela = fontesys.render(txt, 1, (255,255,255))  ##### renderiza o texto na cor desejada
screen.blit(txttela,(50,900)                      ##### coloca na posição 50,900 (tela FHD)
pygame.display.update()                           ##### CARREGA A TELA E EXIBE
```

Comment: É legal você querer ajudar, mas precisa tomar um certo cuidado com formatação, e talvez uma explicação não só dentro do código fosse interessante. Formatei pra tentar deixar mais legível, mas fique à vontade para [edit] conforme achar necessário. Note que para formatar o código usei o botão `{ }` da barra de formatação.